# PyQt4 как изменить цвет кнопки при наведении мыши и при нажатии?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4

Как изменить цвет кнопки при наведении на нее мыши и при ее нажатии?

Кнопка создается на окне без использования классов:

```
button_close = QtGui.QPushButton('Close', main_window)
button_close.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Verdana', 10))
button_close.setGeometry(80, 140, 100, 27)
button_close.setStyleSheet(my_style_button)
button_close.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Цвет фона: белый, при наведении мышки цвет становится красным, а при нажатии – зеленый:

```
button_close.setStyleSheet("""
    QPushButton:hover { background-color: red }
    QPushButton:!hover { background-color: white }
    
    QPushButton:pressed { background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0); }
""")
```